# How to resolve Log aggregation has not completed or is not enabled error in YARN logs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, amazon-emr

I'm using EMR 5.4 and I submit spark job to Yarn

When I try to retrive the log with `yarn logs -applicationId application_1528461193301_0001`, I have the following error :

```
18/06/08 12:38:01 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-10-0-182-144.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.182.144:8032
s3://xxx/apps/root/logs/application_1528461193301_0001 does not exist.
Log aggregation has not completed or is not enabled.
```

Here is my config `/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Where to store container logs.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
    <value>s3://xxx/containers</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Where to aggregate logs to.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
    <value>s3://xxx/apps</value>
  </property>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation yarn logs utility can not be used if logs are aggregated to s3

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-debugging.html

> Note
>
> You cannot currently use log aggregation to Amazon S3 with the yarn
>   logs utility.

you can downlod log files using aws utility

```
aws s3 cp s3://xxx/apps/[applicationId] /your/folder --recursive
```